# Connection on a Principal bundle and transition functions, as in Hitchin's notes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gerbes

This is along the lines of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298437/confusion-in-definition-of-gerbes-in-hitchins-notes)

> Gerbes are not just topological objects: we can do differential geometry with them too. We shall next describe what a connection on a gerbe is.
>
> To begin with, let’s look at a connection on a line bundle which is given
> by transition functions $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\rightarrow S^1\subseteq \mathbb{C}^*$. A connection on consists of $1$ forms $A_\alpha$ defined on $U_\alpha$ such that on a twofold intersection $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ we have $iA_\alpha-iA_\beta=g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}dg_{\alpha\beta}$

I know what is a connection $1$ form (on principal bundle) but not as in above version. I am trying to relate what I know with what is given here.

Let $(P,M,\pi)$ be a principal  $G$ bundle with $\mathfrak{g}=T_eG$ and transition functions $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\rightarrow G$.

> Definition : A connection form on  $P$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$ valued $1$
> form $\omega$ on $P$ such that
>
> - $\omega(p)(A^*(p))=A$ for all $A\in \mathfrak{g}$ and $p\in P$
> - $(\delta_g^*\omega)(p)(v)=Ad_{g^{-1}}(\omega(p)(v))$ for all $p\in P,g\in G$ and $v\in T_pP$.

Given a connection $1$ form $\omega$ on $P$ I am trying to associate a collection  of $1$ forms $\{A_\alpha\}$ with some compatability conditions (here $A_\alpha$ is a $1$ form on $U_\alpha$).

Given local trivialization $\psi_\alpha$, we have a section of $\pi$ namely $\sigma_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow P$ defined as $\sigma_\alpha(x)=\psi_\alpha^{-1}(x,e)$. Given local trivialization $\psi_\beta$, we have a section of $\pi$ namely $\sigma_\beta:U_\beta\rightarrow P$ defined as $\sigma_\beta(x)=\psi_\beta^{-1}(x,e)$.

Suppose $x\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ then, we have $\sigma_\alpha(x)\in \pi^{-1}(x)$ and $\sigma_\beta(x)\in \pi^{-1}(x)$. Thus, there exists $g\in G$ (depending on $x$) such  that $\sigma_\beta(x)=\sigma_\alpha(x)g$. Given $x\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ there is an obvious choice for an element of $G$ namely $g_{\alpha\beta}(x)$. I  see that we have $\sigma_\beta(x)=\sigma_\alpha(x)g_{\alpha\beta}(x)$ for all $x\in U_{\alpha}\cap U_\beta$ i.e., $\sigma_\beta=\sigma_\alpha g_{\alpha\beta}$.

Given a $1$ form $\omega$ on $P$ and we can pull back $\omega$ to $U_\alpha$ under $\sigma_\alpha$ to get $1$ form $\omega_\alpha=\sigma_\alpha^*\omega$ on $U_\alpha$ similarly we can pull back to $U_\beta$ to get $1$ form $\omega_\beta=\sigma_\beta^*\omega$  on $U_\beta$.

As $\sigma_\alpha$ and $\sigma_\beta$ are related by $\sigma_\alpha=\sigma_\beta g_{\alpha\beta}$, one can expect that $\omega_\alpha$ and $\omega_\beta$ are related some how. Given $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_{\alpha\beta}\rightarrow G$ we can produce a $1$ form on $U_\alpha\beta$ as pull back of $\theta$ on $G$ i.e., the canonical $1$ form on $G$ which is a left invariant $1$ form determined by $\theta(e)(A)=A$ for all $A\in \mathfrak{g}$. Let us denote pull back of $\theta$ to $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ by $\theta_{\alpha\beta}$. Then, I am expecting some compatibility  relation between $1$ forms $\omega_\alpha,\omega_\beta$ and $\theta_{\alpha\beta}$ that should come from
$\sigma_\alpha=\sigma_\beta g_{\alpha\beta}$.

EDIT : I could see in Kobayshi and Nomizu that these local connection forms $\sigma_\alpha$ are related by
$$ \sigma_\beta(p)(X_p)=ad(g_{\alpha\beta}(p)^{-1})(\sigma_\alpha(p)(X_p))+\theta_{\alpha\beta}(p)(X_p) \text{ on } U_\alpha\cap U_\beta.$$
In short, we have
$$\sigma_\beta=ad(g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1})\sigma_\alpha+\theta_{\alpha\beta} \text{ on } U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$$

I see that people use $g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}dg_{\alpha\beta}$ (notation of Maurer Cartan differential of a map $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\rightarrow G$) to denote what we have called as $\theta_{\alpha\beta}$. So, in this notation, we have

$$\sigma_\beta=ad(g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1})\sigma_\alpha+g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}d g_{\alpha\beta}\text{ on } U_\alpha\cap U_\beta.$$

**Question** : I am trying to understand how $\sigma_\beta=ad(g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1})\sigma_\alpha+g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}d g_{\alpha\beta}\text{ on } U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ on principal bundles has its similar part as $iA_\alpha-iA_\beta=g_{\alpha\beta}^{-1}dg_{\alpha\beta}$ in case of line bundles.

Any suggestion/reference on how to see this is welcome.

Comment: See eg equation (3.2) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6471

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks, that definitely helps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A  principal $G$-bundle $P\to M$ can be described by an open cover $(U_\alpha)$ of $M$  and a cocycle  $g_{\beta\alpha}: U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\to G$.  The total space  is  the quotient of the disjoint union of the spaces $U_\alpha\times G$ via the equivalence relation

$$ U_\alpha\times g\ni (x, g')\sim (y, g'')\in U_\beta\times G $$
iff
$$ x=y,\;\;g''=g_{\beta\alpha}(x)\cdot g'. $$

A section of a $G$ bundle is then a collection of smooth maps

$$\sigma_\alpha: U_\alpha\to G $$

satisfying the gluing conditions

$$ \sigma_\beta(x)=g_{\beta\alpha}(x)\cdot \sigma_\alpha(x),\;\;\forall x\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta. $$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Question was more about connections than about this identity. I was sure about this identity from my version and also know that when constructing principal bundle from trnaistition functions this condition holds. Please suggest something for Question I have asked about connections on P giving connections on A_\alpha and their compatibility condition.

Comment: Check  the book of Kobayashi and Nomizu.

Comment: I guess I am misunderstanding your statement "A section of a $G$ bundle is then a collection of smooth maps $\sigma_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow G$ [---]" You mean local sections? Or you mean given this collection there exists a (global) section $M\rightarrow P$ of $\pi:P\rightarrow M$

Comment: Can you please clarify my doubt.

Comment: I should have said that the collection $(U_\alpha)$ is an open cover of $M$.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I see that a collection of smooth maps $\sigma_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow G$ such that $\sigma_\beta=g_{\beta\alpha}\sigma_\alpha$ gives a section of principal bundle? I see that suppose there is a local trivialization $\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times G$ then, this collection $\sigma_\alpha:U\alpha\rightarrow G$ gives another trivialization but I do not see how it gives a section.. Can you please add liittle more details

Comment: I was able to see how $\sigma_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow G$ satisfying those conditions would give a section on $G$ bundle. I have seen it for line bundle here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2738235/sections-of-a-vector-bundle?noredirect=1#comment5650633_2738235 I am sure the same idea works for $G$ bundles as well.

Comment: Sir, i was asking about   between local connection forms and your answer mentions about the relation between the sections. So, this does not answer my question in its previous form and also in its current form. Please consider deleting it so that other people can give their answer or kindly consider answering current form of my question.